# WebStorm - disable error for ES2016 double colon (bind operator)

Tags: webstorm

Using the double colon to bind things is great, but WebStorm 11 makes it almost unusable since it throws an error on the first colon (`expression expected`) and then at the end of the expression (`expecting newline or semicolon`). This marks my file as having an error and whenever i do a quick code format (<kbd>Alt+Cmd+L</kbd>) it junks everything up. Any ideas on how to manage this?

Reproduction code:
`const authenticate = promisify(::socket.authenticate);`

Comment: This error comes from the lowest Parser/Lexer level (and not higher Inspection level) -- such errors cannot be disabled/suppressed. This means that IDE MUST be aware of such construct/functionality in order to process your code correctly. So... try latest EAP build (if available) and/or check that JS language version is set to the correct (latest) version is IDE's settings (sorry, not a JS person myself so cannot give you precise answer on actual JS version needed).

Comment: Other than that -- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB -- see if you can find existing ticket and create new one if none found.

Comment: yep, already watching the ticket, but it's 6 month old with no change, so I was hoping there was something I could do on my own...
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-18760

Comment: You should watch [WEB-16614](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-16614) instead. Accordingly to [this comment](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-16614#comment=27-1153651) they *planning* to have it fixed in one of the 11.0.x builds. Try pinging devs there again.

Comment: Note also that the :: syntax probably won't be going forward.. https://github.com/zenparsing/es-function-bind/issues/24#issuecomment-141102543